# Monitoring Next.js app with Azure AppInsights

Tags: azure, monitoring, next.js13, appinsights

I am facing problems in setting up Azure AppInsights monitoring for Next.js app.

I tried by adding client-side libraries (like @microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js and @microsoft/applicationinsights-web). In this case I see logs in AppInsights only in development mode and not with production build.

Does anybody has experience integrating Next.js with AppInsights?